# Bedtools count split reads spanning whole feature

Tags: bedtools

[Note: this is for bedtools v2.30]

I want to count the number of RNA-Seq reads that fully cover a given splice junction. For that, I thought of defining a BED feature around the junction, then using `bedtools coverage`.

Here is a simplified situation:

```
1-BASED POS 1|      10|       20|       30|
CHROMOSOME   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
BED FILE              **                   
BAM READ FWD >>>>>>>>>>                    
BAM READ REV                  <<<
```

We can generate the corresponding example files:

```
echo -e "I\t9\t11\tmy_position\t.\t+" > single_place.bed

echo -e "@HD\tVN:1.4\tSO:coordinate
@SQ\tSN:I\tLN:30
first_read\t99\tI\t1\t255\t10M\t=\t20\t20\tAATTCCGGAA\tDDDDDDDDDD\tNH:i:1\tHI:i:1\tAS:i:127\tnM:i:0
first_mate\t147\tI\t20\t255\t3M\t=\t1\t20\tATC\tDDD\tNH:i:1\tHI:i:1\tAS:i:127\tnM:i:0" | samtools view -b > fwd_only.bam
samtools index fwd_only.bam


cat single_place.bed
I       9       11      my_position     .       +
samtools view fwd_only.bam
first_read      99      I       1       255     10M     =       20      20      AATTCCGGAA      DDDDDDDDDD      NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:127        nM:i:0
first_mate      147     I       20      255     3M      =       1       20      ATC     DDD     NH:i:1  HI:i:1  AS:i:127        nM:i:0
```

The per-base count (with the `-d` option) gives the expected result:

```
coverageBed -d -a single_place.bed -b fwd_only.bam
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       1       1
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       2       0
```

And using a filter `-f 1.0` to only keep reads that cover the entire feature indeed removes our read:

```
coverageBed -a single_place.bed -b fwd_only.bam
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       1       1       2       0.5000000
coverageBed -f 1.0 -a single_place.bed -b fwd_only.bam
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       0       0       2       0.0000000
```

However, in practice, I have a lot of spliced reads, so I wish to use the `-split` option. In that case, the filtering doesn't work anymore:

```
coverageBed -split -f 1.0 -a single_place.bed -b fwd_only.bam
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       1       1       2       0.5000000
```

even though the per-base count is still unchanged:

```
coverageBed -d -split -a single_place.bed -b fwd_only.bam
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       1       1
I       9       11      my_position     .       +       2       0
```

Why does `-split` interfere with `-f 1.0`?

#### With spliced reads

Note, in practice I'm more interested in cases where the reads can be spliced, such as this:

```
1-BASED POS 1|      10|       20|       30|
CHROMOSOME   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
BED FILE              **                    
BAM READ FWD >>>>>>>>>>__>>                
BAM READ REV                  <<<
```

where `_` is a spliced read. The corresponding BAM can be generated with:

```
echo -e "@HD\tVN:1.4\tSO:coordinate
@SQ\tSN:I\tLN:30
first_read\t99\tI\t1\t255\t10M2N2M\t=\t20\t20\tAAAAAAAAAACC\tDDDDDDDDDDDD\tNH:i:1\tHI:i:1\tAS:i:127\tnM:i:0
first_mate\t147\tI\t20\t255\t3M\t=\t1\t20\tATC\tDDD\tNH:i:1\tHI:i:1\tAS:i:127\tnM:i:0" | samtools view -b > fwd_only.bam
samtools index fwd_only.bam
```

In that situation, it seems I need to use `-split` and `-f 1.0`. I thought of filtering *a posteriori* with e.g. `awk '$10>0.5`, but that doesn't seem to work either: when not using `-d`, the output of `coverageBed` does not separate the reads that cover the feature partially vs fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is an issue that has been raised on Github, and that I had unfortunately missed.

This issue happens in `bedtools coverage` (my examples above), but also in `bedtools intersect`. So, I believe this is actually the same issue as [#928](https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2/issues/928). Indeed, switching to bedtools v2.27 solves my issue described above (with v2.30).

Note that this particular issue likely appeared as a consequence of solving issues #773, #750, #673.

My workaround is to use `bedtools intersect` INVERTING the bed and bam, so that I just filter in the reads that match the feature, then count the resulting number of rows.

```
intersectBed -split -bed -wb -F 1.0 \
             -a fwd_only.bam -b single_place.bed | \
  cut -f16 | \
  sort | \
  uniq -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is the issue you're having, but I've encountered a similar situation with coverage estimation when trying to map nanopore cDNA reads to the genome. I have a full workflow for mapping oriented long reads [here](https://dx.doi.org/10.17504/protocols.io.b54iq8ue), but here's a summary of the split issue:

> The default options for BEDTools treat sequence deletions (which happen frequently in nanopore reads) as a drop in coverage, which can make exon hunting and coverage calculation more difficult. I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2/pull/868) to add an additional ignoreD parameter to the command line to allow cDNA reads with split coverage across introns to ignore deletions when considering coverage; this request has now been incorporated into the main BEDtools repository (as of v2.30.0).

Depending on how your mapping is set up, adding `-ignoreD`to your command line may allow spliced reads to be properly counted for coverage with no deletion gaps:

```
$ bedtools genomecov -bga -strand '+' -split -ignoreD -ibam mapped_BC01.sam
chrX    0       7384244 0
chrX    7384244 7384413 1
chrX    7384413 171031299       0

$ bedtools genomecov -bga -strand '+' -split -ignoreD -ibam mapped_BC01_exon.sam
chr11   0       62551499        0
chr11   62551499        62551595        1
chr11   62551595        62552139        0
chr11   62552139        62553212        1
chr11   62553212        122082543       0
```

Comment: I do not think this solves it, as the `split` is to handle the `N`s in the CIGAR string, while these are short reads with no deletion. But by pointing to your PR, you made me find a relevant Github issue that I had somehow missed, thank you! I'll post it as an answer for future reference.